# Schema growth in Oracle 11g

Tags: oracle, schema

what is the best way to get the schema growth in Oracle? I tried using many of the dba_hist_ tables and none of them seem to get me the size and growth of the schema for a specific time (7day) period. These tables seem to hold tablespace growth information, not @ the schema level.

Can somebody help?

Tried the following tables,

dba_hist_tablespace_stat, dba_hist_seg_stat, dba_hist_seg_stat_obj, dba_hist_snapshot etc.

Answer (score 0):

Check this query:

```
SELECT b.tsname tablspc_name ,
  MAX(b.used_size_mb) cur_used_size_mb ,
  ROUND(AVG(inc_used_size_mb),2) avg_incr_mb
FROM
  (SELECT a.days,
    a.tsname ,
    used_size_mb ,
    used_size_mb - LAG (used_size_mb,1) OVER ( PARTITION BY a.tsname ORDER BY a.tsname,a.days) inc_used_size_mb
  FROM
    (SELECT TO_CHAR(sp.begin_interval_time,'MM-DD-YYYY') days ,
      ts.tsname ,
      MAX(ROUND((tsu.tablespace_usedsize* dt.block_size )/(1024*1024),2)) used_size_mb
    FROM dba_hist_tbspc_space_usage tsu ,
      dba_hist_tablespace_stat ts ,
      dba_hist_snapshot sp,
      dba_tablespaces dt
    WHERE tsu.tablespace_id    = ts.ts#
    AND tsu.snap_id            = sp.snap_id
    AND ts.tsname              = dt.tablespace_name
    AND sp.begin_interval_time > sysdate-7
    GROUP BY TO_CHAR(sp.begin_interval_time,'MM-DD-YYYY'),
      ts.tsname
    ORDER BY ts.tsname,
      days
    ) a
  ) b
GROUP BY b.tsname
ORDER BY b.tsname;
```

And group by owner:

```
SELECT  ds.owner as owner, 
  MAX(b.used_size_mb) cur_used_size_mb ,
  ROUND(AVG(inc_used_size_mb),2) avg_incr_mb
FROM
  (SELECT a.days,
    a.tsname ,
    used_size_mb ,
    used_size_mb - LAG (used_size_mb,1) OVER ( PARTITION BY a.tsname ORDER BY a.tsname,a.days) inc_used_size_mb
  FROM
    (SELECT TO_CHAR(sp.begin_interval_time,'MM-DD-YYYY') days ,
      ts.tsname ,
      MAX(ROUND((tsu.tablespace_usedsize* dt.block_size )/(1024*1024),2)) used_size_mb
    FROM dba_hist_tbspc_space_usage tsu ,
      dba_hist_tablespace_stat ts ,
      dba_hist_snapshot sp,
      dba_tablespaces dt
    WHERE tsu.tablespace_id    = ts.ts#
    AND tsu.snap_id            = sp.snap_id
    AND ts.tsname              = dt.tablespace_name
    AND sp.begin_interval_time > sysdate-7
    GROUP BY TO_CHAR(sp.begin_interval_time,'MM-DD-YYYY'),
      ts.tsname
    ORDER BY ts.tsname,
      days
    ) a
  ) b
JOIN dba_segments ds on ds.tablespace_name = b.tsname
GROUP BY ds.owner
ORDER BY ds.owner;
```

Comment: Yes. I tried this. This only lists all the tablespace details, not the schemas. This works fine on table space, but my tablespace contains about 12 schemas. I'm looking for the stats on one of the schemas.

Comment: 73374.63 90.88
73374.63 90.88
73374.63 90.88
73374.63 90.88
73374.63 90.88
73374.63 90.88
73374.63 90.88
73374.63 90.88
73374.63 90.88
73374.63 90.88
73374.63 90.88
73374.63 90.88
73374.63 90.88

Comment: This query returns the same size for all the 13 schemas as below that i have inside the tablespace.

total size:73374.63MB Growth:90.88MB

I think the reason is the inner query. The below query is still run on the tablespace and it's increment.

SELECT TO_CHAR(sp.begin_interval_time,'MM-DD-YYYY') days ,
      ts.tsname ,
      MAX(ROUND((tsu.tablespace_usedsize* dt.block_size )/(1024*1024),2)) used_size_mb
    FROM dba_hist_tbspc_space_usage tsu ,
      dba_hist_tablespace_stat ts ,
      dba_hist_snapshot sp,
      dba_tablespaces dt
    WHERE tsu.tablespace_id    = ts.ts#
    .............